# Accesing ASP tag's content of Master page in content page

Tags: asp.net

I am new with ASP.net and having a following problem:

My Master Page has Body and Header tags with classes like this

```
<body class="bg">   
<header class="header">
</header>
</body>
```

I want to remove the classes from content page when they load. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use JavaScript to remove it on the client side when the page loads. On the client side there is no concept of elements from a master page or from content pages. For client side JavaScript/jQuery, all elements are equally accessible.

Check the .removeAttr() jQuery function here :

http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Use **body** and **head** element selector for jQuery and it will work.